# How do I promote a user automatically in Mediawiki and create a log of those promotions?

Tags: mediawiki

I control a Mediawiki site. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ALog&type=rights&user=&page=&year=&month=-1&tagfilter=&hide_thanks_log=1&hide_patrol_log=1&hide_tag_log=1&hide_review_log=1) you can see users being automatically updated and added into the extended confirmed user group.

If I have a group called "util" where I just want to add relevant code to enable autopromotion with a log entry like that, make an edit and get promoted automatically into the group before removing the bit of code would it be possible? Also what code would I have to use to gain a level of access like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$wgAutopromote`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAutopromote) (or [`$wgAutopromoteOnce`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAutopromoteOnce) if you want to be able to manually remove people from the group). It would look something like this:

```
$wgAutopromote = [
    'util' => [ APCOND_EDITCOUNT, 1 ],
];
$wgImplicitGroups[] = 'util'; // for good measure, hide the group in the normal group management interfaces
```

Comment: So it would be something like this:

`$wgAutopromoteOnce['onEdit']['util'] = array(
 '&',
 array( APCOND_EDITCOUNT, 1 ),
);`

if I wanted to be able to manually remove a user.

Comment: You can omit the `&` since you only have one condition: `$wgAutopromoteOnce['onEdit']['util'] = [ APCOND_EDITCOUNT, 1 ];`